# Ruby on Rails Relationship Troubles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relational-database

I am creating a relationship database between 'property' and 'property_images' whenever I try to reference the property_images by the following call `= image_tag property.property_images.image_url.to_s, :size => '240x180'` I get the following error

```
undefined method `image_url' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fe8d2e95300>
```

though if I do `<h1><%= property_image.property.title %></h1>` it returns the correct value

I have my 2 models like so

```
 class PropertyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  attr_accessible :feature, :image, :property_id
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end


    class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agency
  has_many :property_images
```

so the relationship should be working the way I want, though it doesnt appear to be case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`property.property_images` is not a `PropertyImage`, it's a collection of property images.

You have to tell which one you want to use, for example the first :

```
= image_tag property.property_images.first.image_url.to_s, :size => '240x180'
```

Comment: that was so easy, yet i couldnt seem to see the forrest from the trees. thanks